# Loading images angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently trying to load an image into an img tag. My issue is that the loading of the image cannot be done through a specific src url. so I have created a function which returns the image. I am currently calling the function in the following format  with no image been loaded. Please note i have verified that the function does indeed return a value as an array buffer. Thank you for your help!

code:

JS-

```
//use .factory Img object to return arraybuffer value
$scope.getImage = function(productid) {
      console.log(productid);
      par = {id: [productid]};
      Img.getImage(par).$promise.then(
        function(data){
          console.log("success:" + data); //I am able to see this result but not display in img tag
          return data;
        },
        function(data){
          console.log("error" + data);
        }
      );
    }
```

HTML-

```
<img ng-src="{{getimage(id)}}">
```

Comment: Hi paul590, I'm not to sure what you're asking?

Comment: `getimage` is asynchronous, it doesn't return an URL, it's a promise.

Comment: @Derek I apologize for the confusion, I am wondering how can I load an image to my img tag when I dont have an actual url but a function that returns a arraybuffer.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes the getimage is a promise, since it returns an arraybuffer is there a way to add this response to the img tag?

Comment: `getimage` returns nothing. The callback of your promise does. You can't synchronously assign an asynchronous value. 1) Get your data. 2) Store it in a variable in your controller. 3) Use this variable as source for your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `Img.getImage(par).$promise` is asynchronous. You can't return a value inside.

It's not the best solution but you can do somthing like that :

JS :

```
$scope.getImage = function(productid) {
  console.log(productid);
  par = {id: [productid]};
  Img.getImage(par).$promise.then(
    function(data){
      console.log("success:" + data); //I am able to see this result but not display in img tag
      scope.productionPicturePath = data;
      return data;
    },
    function(data){
      console.log("error" + data);
    }
  );
}
```

HTML : `<img ng-src="{{productionPicturePath}}">`

Comment: I could be making a rookie mistake but when i load the image this way, its unable to load its trying to look at my server with the following localhost:8080/result of data i receive

Comment: I figured it out this did the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your `getImage` function does not return the array buffer from the service, because you are obtaining it from a promise. If you want to get a value from an asynchronous operation and bind it to the view, you need to set it as a `$scope` parameter:

```
$scope.getImage = function(productid) {
      $scope.currentArrayBuffer = null;
      par = {id: [productid]};
      Img.getImage(par).$promise.then(
        function(data){
          console.log("success:" + data); 
          $scope.currentArrayBuffer = data;
        },
        function(data){
          console.log("error" + data);
        }
      );
    }
```

And then:

```
<img ng-src="{{currentArrayBuffer}}">
```

Comment: As I stated on the response above I could be making a rookie mistake but when i load the image this way, its unable to load its trying to look at my server with the following localhost:8080/result of data i receive